# Exception Raising in Urllib2 - Python

Tags: python, try-catch, urllib2

I'm trying to use the following code to check whether a given site is online:

```
url_list = ["www.apple.com", "www.invalidurlname.com"]
for i in url_list:
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen(i, timeout = 1)
    except urllib2.URLError:
        print "fail"
    else:
        print "pass"
```

It should produce:

```
pass
fail
```

However when I run it I get the following error:

```
  File "scanpb.py", line 7
urllib2.urlopen("http://apple.com", timeout = 1)
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Where have I gone wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you're mixing tabs and spaces. That line isn't properly indented according to the error.

Comment: Turns out I had 4 spaces and then a tab. Didn't know that would cause a problem, thanks very much :)

Comment: The error shown clearly does not correspond to the code shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed tabs and spaces (displaying tabs as `tab` and spaces as `.`:

```
tab try:
....tab urllib2.urlopen(i, timeout = 1)
```

Set your editor to either one, and use your editor's replace function to replace all occurences (you can match tabs with `\t` in regex mode).